# How os.environ python get default user environment variables

Tags: python, linux

OS is RHEL7, I'd like to get HOSTTYPE env variable of server. From shell, echo $HOSTTYPE or type `set` command, it shows output of $HOSTTYPE

```
# echo $HOSTTYPE
x86_64
```

But when I get it from os.environ python, it show KeyError, I'd like to ask how Python get default user environment variables for os.environ?

```
print(os.environ['HOSTTYPE'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/virtualenv/HDBTestEnvironment/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'HOSTTYPE'
```

From OS, how can I check where HOSTTYPE is set. I find/grep in below location, but it's not found.

```
# grep -r HOSTTYPE /etc/*
# grep -r HOSTTYPE ~/.*
```

Answer (score 0):

If environment variable not set/get through environment or os than you can you python to set it

```
os.environ['HOSTTYPE'] = 'x86_64'
print(os.environ['HOSTTYPE'])
```

output:

```
x86_64
```

or just use `bash` to set environment variable like

```
export HOSTTYPE="x86_64"
```

and for varifing it use:

```
echo "$HOSTTYPE"
```

output:

```
x86_64
```